Why is Russia pushing for the Zangezur corridor now?
Back in August:

MOSCOW, August 19. /TASS/. Russia is at a loss as to why Yerevan is sabotaging the agreements on setting up logistical corridors that run through Armenia’s Syunik Province, Russian Foreign Minister Sergey Lavrov said.

Then,

Iran’s Foreign Ministry has "invited" Russian Ambassador Alexei Dedov to express Tehran's concerns over Moscow's support for the Zangezur corridor project, according to the Iranian government's news website (Dolat.ir) on September 3.

The Iranian ambassador to Armenia also reiterated their opposition.
For a while it appeared that Azerbaijan wasn't pushing much for that corridor through Armenia. So, what does Russia stand to gain pushing the Zangezur corridor now, even though Iran grumbles about it?

Everyone follows the benefits of its own country first. Some countries follow their interests with no law/ethic border, some others follow their own interests within the borders of law/ethic. Russia and Iran have serious interests in cooperation with each other, but they have also benefits in not being together in every possible respect. Russia and China both have refused to used veto in cases against Iran in some situations in the past, so might they do the same in future. That the relation between the US and Israel is beyond this pattern, makes Israel (at least in view of some politicians) almost the 51st state of the US, and somewhat the true owner (through the lobbies) of the US, and not so very independent country in real life. This is not the same relation between Iran and Russia. Russia follows its own interests, like being afraid of Azerbaijan tending so much toward the West, maybe uniting with Turkey through the corridor, and finally becoming a member of Nato, a new threat from the south. Also, Azerbaijan, historically a Shia part of Iran, is now several years that have great ties with Israel, and Israel's oil is now prepared from there, and is thus so important for the US, and that could be a lever for Russia to play in that ground as well. There might be other reasons as well, though I'm not much familiar with the situation there.

"being afraid of Azerbaijan tending so much toward the West, maybe uniting with Turkey through the corridor, and finally becoming a member of Nato, a new threat from the south" -- interesting, but in that case Russia should be opposing Az ambitions, which is not what they're doing right now.

Yes and no, to my understanding this might bring Russia to the bottom, and they find a role in a region which may otherwise end up against Iran and them, both  (if my understanding is correct). Why Iran opposes this also has its own causes. Meanwhile, cf here (in Persian).

Your statements are quite exaggerated. Russia doesn't "push" the corridor more than calling for "following the spirit and the letter of the series of trilateral agreements between the Russian, Azerbaijani, and Armenian leaders, which were reached in 2020-2022". The agreement says that the corridor to be open under the control of Russian border guards.  Armenia want to have the corridor under their exclusive control and Pashinyan recently used to say "there was no such agreement" and that made Lavrov angry.
Azerbaijan doesn't push because they found an alternative path through Iran, and the use of this path will leave Armenia without profit (even small revenge sweet).
Iran want these money so they consider the initial agreement on the corridor of Zangezur threatening their interests. That's why they encourage Armenia to be stubborn.

At least my Azerbaijani friend see the situation this way.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Just a bad wording perhaps. I changed it to emphasize that opening of the corridor was a part of the agreement that was violated by Armenia.

Mkay, where did Pashinian say "there was no such agreement"? That needs more context. And if he said it, how does your link prove that Armenia agreed to it? AFAICT, the page section you link to is an agreement between Russia and Azerbaijan. That's like gifting someone else's cheese, to use a joke from the region. There was a trilateral statement too, but it doesn't seem to contain a ref to this corridor.

Yeah, as I suspected, Armenia invoked the vague wording of the trilateral statement (which unlike the agreement between Russia and Az didn't mention the corridor) to say that Armenia didn't agree to any such corridor.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Original text of the agreement is clear: "The Republic of Armenia shall guarantee the security of transport connections between the western regions of the Republic of Azerbaijan and the Nakhchivan Autonomous Republic in order to arrange unobstructed movement of persons, vehicles and cargo in both directions. The Border Guard Service of the Russian Federal Security Service shall be responsible for overseeing the transport connections." And this agreement was explicitly signed by Aliyev and Pashinyan.

Interesting. I suppose since that was a ceasefire agreement (para 1), ceasefire which ultimately didn't seem to last, I'm guessing that's why Armenia is not even referring to it, but the 2021 agreements, although the latter technically don't supersede the ceasefire. BTW, is the text of the 2023 ceasefire available somewhere?
